# Prove that the expression $\frac{\gcd(n,m)}{n}\binom{n}{m}$ is an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

> Prove that the expression
> $$\frac{\gcd(n,m)}{n}\binom{n}{m}$$
> is an integer for all pairs of integers $n\ge m \ge1$.

#### My work so  far:

If $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then
$$\frac{\gcd(n,m)}{n}\binom{n}{m}=\frac1n\cdot \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}=\frac{(n-1)!}{m!(n-m)!} \in \mathbb Z$$
If $\gcd(m,n)=d>1$

*I need help here*

Comment: Even in the gcd=1 case, it's not *immediately* obvious that dividing $\binom{n}{m}$ by $n$ gives an integer. [Just saying that requires a proof.]